# Laravel 5.2 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 in single post view

Tags: laravel-5

I'm a beginner in Laravel and I need your help. I have successfully displayed the contents of my post controller on the index page, but I want to be able to click on each post and have it displayed on another page. I'm using Laravel 5.2.

Here's my controller:

`

```
public function show($id)
{   
$post= Post::find($id);
 return View::make('posts.viewpost')->with('post', $post);
   }
```

`

Here is my Route:

`Route::get('posts/viewpost/{id}','PostsController@show');`

Here's my index page which currently displays all posts:

`

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
{{$post->title}}
{{$post->description}}
<a href="{{ url('posts/viewpost', $post->id) }}"> Read More</a>
@endforeach
```

`

I want to be able to click on 'Read More' and have each post displayed on a new page viewpost.blade.php

After running the project and I try to click each post, I keep getting this error page:
[shown in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqKQR.png)

I really do not understand why this error appears each time I click on one of the posts, please guys help me. Thanks in anticipation for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with url:: to may be its not taking your base path
Try with this code

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('posts/viewpost/'.$post->id) }}">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have been able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I've been able to figure it out.

I had to update this line:

```
<a href="{{ url('posts/viewpost', $post->id) }}"> Read More</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="{{ url('posts', $post->id) }}"> Read More</a>
```